# find closing anchor tag from the string and add some value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find closing anchor tag. And add Icon after the closing tag.The inside value is coming as a string from database.I need to extract the value and append with icon.

For example

```
  <p>This is a paragraph and link <a href="#">test</a>testdsfasffd<a href="#">test1</a>fdfdfdfdfd</p>
```

In the above example I have paragraph tag inside I have two anchor tag.

Actually the result will come as  [Test added plus icon](http://test) testdsfasffd &  [Test1 added plus icon 2](http://Test1) fdfdfdfdfd

First I need to find the closing anchor tag then i need to append the icon from other functions

Current I am trying like this

```
var string = '<p>This is a paragraph and link <a href="#">test</a>testdsfasffd<a href="#">test1</a>fdfdfdfdfd</p>';
```

I am setting an pattern

```
var closingAnchor = '</a>';
string.split(closingAnchor);
```

after this i need to append icon from other function using **for loop**. I am getting struggle here kindly please help me.

Comment: parsing HTML is a bad idea, create a div, set the innerHTML, find the element, append the new element.

Comment: Kindly please help me as i already tried i was not getting any idea :(

Answer (score 1):

Splitting HTML is normally a bad bad idea. So just do it with the DOM.

```js
var string = '<p>This is a paragraph and link <a href="#">test</a>testdsfasffd<a href="#">test1</a>fdfdfdfdfd</p>';

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = string;
var anchors = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {

  var text = document.createTextNode(' TEXT TO ADD ');
  var sibling = anchors[i].nextSibling;
  if(sibling) {
      anchors[i].parentNode.insertBefore(text, sibling);
  } else {
      anchors[i].parentNode.appendChild(text);                        
  }
}
console.log(div.innerHTML);

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Hi one small query for example if i have div id i need the result to be displyad in the result

<Div id="sample"></DIV>

i tried removing creteElement and add the document.getElementByID("sample")

Comment: but I am getting error 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: is that possible can i call one more function inside the createTextNode or some other property

Comment: thank you so much for your helping :)

var text = document.createTextNode(' welcomeText() ');

function welcomeText(){
document.write("welcome");
}

is this will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82734/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: `//` for regex, `<\/a>` for `</a>`, `g` for search all

```js
var string = '<p>This is a paragraph and link <a href="#">test</a>testdsfasffd<a href="#">test1</a>fdfdfdfdfd</p>';
var output = string.replace(/<\/a>/g, '</a>YOUR APPENDEE');
alert(output);
```

Hope this helps.